# array nao funciona ao criar polyline leaflet

Tags: php, mysql, array, maps

[image: marker no mapa]

Alguem poderia me ajudar, estou com dificuldade para extrair latitude e longitude de uma array em PHP e adicionar ao mapa leaflet (JavaScript). As coordenadas estão corretas com 'print' mas apenas uma localização é marcada.

**CODIGO UTILIZADO PARA OBTER OS DADOS DO BANCO MYSQL**

```
<?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_alerta)) {

        $imei = $row['imei'];
        $identificacao = $row['identificacao'];
        $lat = $row['latitude'];
        $lon = $row['longitude'];
        $endereco = $row['endereco'];
        $data = $row['data'];
        $hora = $row['hora'];
        $velocidade = $row['velocidade'];
        $tipo = $row['tipo'];
        
        $string = '[' . floatval($row['latitude']) . ', ' .$row['longitude'] . ']';
        
        $lats[] = $lat;
        $lons[] = $lon;
    }
    
    foreach ($lats as $lat) {
        echo $coords = $lat.",".$lon;
        // echo $lon;
        //echo $coord = [$coord];
    }
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var coord = "<?php echo $coords?>";
    var lat = "<?php echo $lat?>";
    var lon = "<?php echo $lon?>"
    console.log(coord);
    
    var map = L.map('map').setView([lat,lon], 13);
    
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
    
    L.marker([lat, lon]).addTo(map)
        .bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup.<br> Easily customizable.')
        .openPopup();
    
    
        var coords = [[lat +','+lon]];
        for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
        console.log(coords[i]);
    }
    var pointA = new L.LatLng(lat, lon);
    var pointB = new L.LatLng(lat, lon);
    var coords = [pointA, pointB];
            
    
    //var coord = "<?php echo $coords ?>";
    alert(coords);
    coords.forEach(function(coordinate) {
        new L.Marker(coordinate).addTo(map);
    });
    var polyline = L.polyline(coords, {color: 'red', className: 'west_side_drive'}).addTo(map);
    
    map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
</script>
```